# Horizontally center absolute images

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute, responsive

I have a relatively position wrapper around three absolutely positioned images.  How can I center these images inside the wrapper without changing the 'left' value so that I can make this module fluid responsive?

My html:

```
    <div class="illustrations">
       <img src="http://fillmurray.com/175/112" alt="" class="platform desktop"> 
       <img src="http://fillmurray.com/143/110" alt="" class="platform tablet" style="left: 110px;"> 
       <img src="http://fillmurray.com/40/87" alt="" class="platform mobile" style="left: 230px;"> 
    </div>
```

See my fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/gjexgw86/

Just want to always have the images centered without changing the absolute 'left' values.

---

Comment: Why are you using `position: absolute;` and `left` if you want to completely ignore them? I'm wondering in what way hard-coding positioning makes something more "fluid" responsive. I think we may need to take one step back and get to the bottom of that issue before we address this. That being said, if you want to apply the absolute positioning based on screen-size, then just use `@media` in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the `left` value, you'll have to change their `translate` value.

Not sure how you're scripting the whole thing, but you'd use

```
transform:translateX(-125px);
```

or however much you need to move them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for responsive way of arranging the images, here I did with Bootstrap.

Check here : https://jsfiddle.net/my23wuxz/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align:center;"><img src="http://fillmurray.com/175/112" alt=""> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align:center;"><img src="http://fillmurray.com/143/110" alt="" > </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align:center;"><img src="http://fillmurray.com/40/87" alt="" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a responsive result, you need to set relative positions between images instead absolute values (absolute left position) :

See in https://jsfiddle.net/gjexgw86/2/ using  negative margin-left between images and let the outer container center the content.

```
.illustrations {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:140px;
}

.platform {
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}


<div class="illustrations">
                        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/175/112" alt="" class="platform desktop">
                        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/143/110" alt="" class="platform tablet" style="margin-left: -65px;">
                        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/40/87" alt="" class="platform mobile" style="margin-left: -30px;">
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may give a try to both `right` and `lef`t coordonates and use `margin:auto;`

```css
.illustrations {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: center;
  height:140px;
  /* see me and my center */
  border: solid;
  background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50% ),linear-gradient(to top, transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50% )
}

.platform {
  transform: translatey(-50%);/*transform would be for vertical centering , optionnal */
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right:0;/* add this to center */
  margin:70px auto;/* 70px from + transform would be for vertical centering , optionnal */
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  }
.illustrations:hover .platform {
  /* see behind */
  opacity:0.5
}
```

```html
<div class="illustrations">
  <img src="http://fillmurray.com/175/112" alt="" class="platform desktop">
  <img src="http://fillmurray.com/143/110" alt="" class="platform tablet" style="left: 110px;">
  <img src="http://fillmurray.com/40/87" alt="" class="platform mobile" style="left: 230px;">
</div>
```

**Notice that :**

- `left:0;`+ `right:0;` = in the midddle
- `left:110px;`+ `right:0;` = 110px away from middle
- `left:230px;`+ `right:0;` = 230px away from middle

https://jsfiddle.net/gjexgw86/4/